# Why does this code compile in Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: c++

This might be a noobish question.

While migrating a project from Visual Studio 2003 to 2017 I noticed the code would error out in line 85 with 'undefined identifier'. This makes sense to me because `nCurrPel` doesn't seem to exist within that scope.

However, the exact same code appears to compile just fine in Visual Studio 2003. What's going on here?

Full code below, refer to commented section:

```cpp
LTBOOL CompressLMData(const int *pData, int width, int height, int *pOutBuffer, int &outLen)
{
    if((pData == NULL) || (pOutBuffer == NULL))
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if((width > LIGHTMAP_MAX_PIXELS_I) || (height > LIGHTMAP_MAX_PIXELS_I))
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    int nBufferLen = width * height * 3;
    int nSpanLen = 0;
    int* pOutPos = pOutBuffer;

    for(int nCurrPel = 0; nCurrPel < nBufferLen; nCurrPel += 3)
    {
        int nRunLen = 1;
        for(int nRunPel = nCurrPel + 3; nRunPel < nBufferLen; nRunPel += 3, nRunLen++)
        {
            if(nRunLen > 127)
            {
                break;
            }

            if( (pData[nCurrPel + 0] != pData[nRunPel + 0]) ||
                (pData[nCurrPel + 1] != pData[nRunPel + 1]) ||
                (pData[nCurrPel + 2] != pData[nRunPel + 2]) )
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(nRunLen >= 2)
        {
            if(nSpanLen > 0)
            {
                OutputSpan(false, nSpanLen, &pData[nCurrPel - nSpanLen * 3], pOutPos);
            }

            OutputSpan(true, nRunLen, &pData[nCurrPel], pOutPos);
            nSpanLen = 0;
            nCurrPel += (nRunLen - 1) * 3;
        }
        else
        {
            nSpanLen++;
            if(nSpanLen > 127)
            {
                OutputSpan(false, nSpanLen, &pData[nCurrPel - (nSpanLen - 1) * 3], pOutPos);
                nSpanLen = 0;
            }
        }       
    }

    //How does this work? nCurrPel is not defined
    if(nSpanLen > 0)
    {
        OutputSpan(false, nSpanLen, &pData[nCurrPel - nSpanLen * 3], pOutPos);
    }

    outLen = (int)(pOutPos - pOutBuffer);
    ASSERT( (outLen >= 4 * (width * height / 128)) &&
            (outLen <= (width * height * 3 + (width * height + 127) / 128)) );

    return LTTRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to do with the scope of the `for` loop.

The Microsoft Visual C++ compiler before version 8 (2005, 2003, 2002, 6.0, etc) "hoisted" the scope of variables declared inside the `for` statement to the parent scope. After Visual Studio 2008 (version 9) the compiler conforms to the C++ specification which requires those variables to be scoped only to the `for` statement and its body.

Non-compliant C++ that's accepted by Visual C++ 2003 and 2005:

```
cout << bar << endl; // error: `bar` isn't defined yet

for( int bar = 0; bar < 10; bar++ ) // `bar` is defined here and it can be used within the `for( ... )` statement parenthesis.
{
    cout << bar << endl; // this 
}

cout << bar << endl; // the life of `bar` extends after its `for` statement to the end of the parent scope
```

Since Visual C++ 2008 the life of `bar` is restricted to the `for` statement parenthesis and the statement body and *not* to the parent scope:

```
cout << bar << endl; // error: `bar` isn't in-scope yet

for( int bar = 0; bar < 10; bar++ ) // `bar` is defined here and it can be used within the `for( ... )` statement parenthesis.
{
    cout << bar << endl; // OK
}

cout << bar << endl; // error: `bar` is not in scope
```

To fix this, you can either manually declare and initialize the `for` loop variables in the parent scope or use a separate variable to hold the last value, like so:

Approach 1: Declaration moved to parent scope:

```
int bar = 0;
for( ; bar < 10; bar++ )
{
     cout << bar << endl;
}

cout << bar << endl;
```

Approach 2: Separate variable declared in parent scope:

```
int last_bar = 0; // Set an initial value in case the for loop body is never evaluated.
for( int bar = 0; bar < 10; bar++ )
{
    cout << bar << endl;

    last_bar = bar;
}

cout << last_bar << endl;
```

Comment: Or move the `int bar` declaration to just before the `for` loop, then you won't have to make any other changes to the code.  Might also be helpful to mention that the original C++ language had the wider scope and Microsoft was slow in implementing the change when  the scope was narrowed.

Comment: You can, although I totally do not recommend it, enable the old behavior with the /Zc:forScope flag. It's on the language page of the project settings.